# validate of check boxes in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

need to validate a four check box called sports, singing, playing and  others. 
If i select others check box then it must show a text field so that i can enter the values in that text box.
write a dynamic action code on Oracle Apex for this validation.

Comment: i,m in doubt where exactly i need to add the dynamic action.

Comment: Have you read this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/advnc_dynamic_actions.htm#CIHCFDGB ???

Comment: You need to add the dynamic action to the "others" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

In APEX, there is no need for 4 checkboxes. Create 1 checkbox that uses an LOV.

This isn't a validation either, simply create a Dynamic Action with the following properties:

### Main Properties

- Event: Change
- Selection Type: Item(s)
- Item: [P1_CHECKBOX]
- Condition: Equal to
- Value: OTHERS

#### TRUE ACTION

- Action: Show
- Fire when Result is: True
- Fire on page load: Yes
- Selection Type: Item(s)
- Item: [P1_TEXT]

#### FALSE ACTION

- Action: Hide
- Fire when Result is: False
- Fire on page load: Yes
- Selection Type: Item(s)
- Item: [P1_TEXT]